# Regular Expression match and extract using group

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to match "1) Exception Information" or "2) Exception Information" and extract the digit using regular expression Match and Group

I'm using

```
Regex.Match("1) Exception Information", @"\d[) Exception Information]").Groups[0].Value
```

but this returns me "1)" and not "1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code will do what you intended:

```
Regex.Match("1) Exception Information", @"(\d)\) Exception Information").Groups[1].Value
```

Your current regex pattern has problems:

```
\d[) Exception Information]
```

This will match a single digit, followed by a *single* character coming from the following set of characters in brackets: `[) Exception Information]`.  In your original string, the parenthesis following the `1` would match, and so your match comes back as `1)`.

Another note, I used `(\d)` in my corrected pattern, which will match and *capture* that single digit.  Then, to access the first (and only) capture group, we can use `Groups[1]`.  `Groups[0]` will return the entire matched pattern, which in this case coincides with the input string.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the detailed explanation.